# How do you return text if a query is true in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to return "Yes" if a value in Years!B:B matches a value in Pending!B:B, otherwise return "No". I've attemped this in Pending!A1 and received the error below:

"Function IF parameter 1 expects boolean values. But 'southeast asia' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean".

I had a partial success in Pending!A2, but I don't want to return the actual value if there is a match. Any ideas on how to curb the text/boolean issue?

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZITpCNuIiMeKZe6ZR0stkE8s163NilUhHVl_XegOcyk/edit#gid=397563551)

Comment: Sorry, I just made it public. I'm not sure how to make it more clear though. Take a look at the sheet and if it's still unclear I'll try to rephrase. I searched through a number of posts and couldn't find one similar.

Comment: It's in any row. Below is the formula returning the error.

=IF(QUERY(Years!B:B,"select B where B = '"&B:B&"'"),"Yes","No")

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(<test>,<output if true>,<output if false>)
```

Therefore:

`=IF(Pending!B1=Years!B1,"Yes","No")` should work for you

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work since B1 on one sheet will not always correspond to that exact cell of B in the other sheet. :/

Comment: What about: `=IF(COUNTIF(Years!B:B,Pending!B1)>0,"Yes","No")`